# npm install -g . doesn't copy, fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, babeljs

The npm developer docs say to [make sure your package installs globally before publishing](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#before-publishing-make-sure-your-package-installs-and-works) by running `npm install -g .`. I'm trying to build an ES6 CLI package that can be installed and run globally, but after running Babel to transpile it (with the `es2015` plugin), the global install on my machine fails.

[I've created a simple demo ES6 project that reproduces the error](https://github.com/orlade/es6-test). Cloning and running `npm install -g .` throws the error in the README:

```
$ npm install -g .

> es6-test@0.0.1 prepublish /Users/me/dev/es6-test
> npm run build


> es6-test@0.0.1 build /Users/me/dev/es6-test
> babel --out-dir es5/ src/

src/bin/app.js -> es5/bin/app.js
src/core/location.js -> es5/core/location.js
npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/5.4.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "."
npm ERR! node v5.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/es6-test/es5/bin/app
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall chmod

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/es6-test/es5/bin/app'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/me/dev/es6-test/npm-debug.log
```

Am I doing something wrong? I've tried a few different commands, with both Babel and NPM, but ultimately nothing seems to get copied into `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`.

```
$ node -v
v5.4.0

$ npm -v
3.3.12
```

EDIT: The error appears to be the same with the latest node and v0.10.24, with and without `sudo`. The logfile says:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/Cellar/node/5.4.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'i',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   '.gs' ]
2 info using npm@3.3.12
3 info using node@v5.4.0
4 silly loadCurrentTree Starting
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData .gs
8 silly fetchOtherPackageData .gs
9 silly cache add args [ '.gs', null ]
10 verbose cache add spec .gs
11 silly cache add parsed spec Result {
11 silly cache add   raw: '.gs',
11 silly cache add   scope: null,
11 silly cache add   name: null,
11 silly cache add   rawSpec: '.gs',
11 silly cache add   spec: '/Users/me/dev/es6-test/.gs',
11 silly cache add   type: 'local' }
12 error addLocal Could not install /Users/me/dev/es6-test/.gs
13 silly fetchPackageMetaData Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/me/dev/es6-test/.gs'
13 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Error (native)
13 silly fetchPackageMetaData  error for .gs { [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/me/dev/es6-test/.gs']
13 silly fetchPackageMetaData   errno: -2,
13 silly fetchPackageMetaData   code: 'ENOENT',
13 silly fetchPackageMetaData   syscall: 'open',
13 silly fetchPackageMetaData   path: '/Users/me/dev/es6-test/.gs' }
14 silly rollbackFailedOptional Starting
15 silly rollbackFailedOptional Finishing
16 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Starting
17 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Finishing
18 silly install printInstalled
19 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/me/dev/es6-test/.gs'
19 verbose stack     at Error (native)
20 verbose cwd /Users/me/dev/es6-test
21 error Darwin 14.5.0
22 error argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/5.4.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "i" "-g" ".gs"
23 error node v5.4.0
24 error npm  v3.3.12
25 error path /Users/me/dev/es6-test/.gs
26 error code ENOENT
27 error errno -2
28 error syscall open
29 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/me/dev/es6-test/.gs'
29 error enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
29 error enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
30 verbose exit [ -2, true ]
```

Comment: go to root (your project) then call it with sudo, Also set your npm-debug.log file path, give permission.

Comment: `sudo` doesn't seem to make a difference. What permission should I set on which files? I've attached the npm logfile output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `"bin"` property of the `package.json` points to an `app.js` file in `es5/bin` but there is no `app.js` file. You'll need to point it to the `csp.js` file:

**package.json**

```
"bin": {
    "csp": "es5/bin/csp.js"
},
```

Comment: Right, sorry, I just forgot to rename that, but unfortunately it doesn't help. I've changed it to `app.js` but it's the same error.

Comment: I meant you should change it to `csp.js`. I've tested this using the repo you created.

Comment: I mean I changed all instanced of `csp` to `app`, including in the package. `csp` was something else I was working on, but for all intents and purposes it's the same, so long as everything is named consistently. I've fixed the repo now, and it's still the same (updated the log above, too).

Comment: Aaaaah, got it. It still didn't work because I changed it to `es5/bin/app` instead of `es5/bin/app.js`. Now it works! I didn't think it should be any more complicated than that. Thanks very much!